# STYLEREF "Headline 3": Numbered 2.1.3 how to get only the last level number (3)

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes, numbering

I have a numbered list with 3 levels:

```
1 Title
...
2 Title
2.1 Title
2.1.1 Title #1
2.1.2 Title #2
2.1.3 Title #3
...
2.2 Title
3 Title
```

My target is to get automatically the correct number after #...
Using:

```
STYLEREF "Headline 3" \n
```

I get "2.1.1" instead of just "1", "2.1.2" instead of just "2" and so on

how can I solve this?
Looking around it seems not possible to trim the string I get in output...
there is any good way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Again, the simplest way is to not use that numbering style. In other words, have "3" instead of "2.1.3."

The [StyleRef Field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF) is acting as designed. I may simply be exposing my ignorance, but as far as I know, there is no way with fields to manipulate strings in Word. Fields can do some manipulation of numbers. "2.1.3" is not a number but rather a string. With visual basic for applications, you can manipulate strings, but this is not going to be dynamic, changing as you add and delete sections.

You could possibly add a SEQ field and display it as white in your text and use the StyleRef field to pull that. This would be very difficult to maintain and would be a nightmare for the user who does not know what is going on.

Another possibility that I explored and could not get to work was to add a separate parallel list to generate the number.

The following links may be useful to others who find this question but do not answer your question.

- Microsoft [documentation on the StyleRef Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-styleref-field-4ad557c2-c8ab-48ba-8fe3-901d0a5775d0)
- Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's [Useful StyleRef Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/StyleRef.htm)